# Fable: The Lost Chapters Quests Stuck

Tags: fable

I am playing Fable: The Lost Chapters on the PC, and I have a couple of quests that will just not get out of my quest log. The book quest is one and the chicken kicking is the other. I have already gotten silver keys for both and a chicken hat from the chicken kicking. I have not gotten the emote but it will not give it to me regardless of the score I get. Am I missing something or are they just stuck in my quest log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an independent source, namely an FAQ on gamefaqs that says the quests I am talking about **never go away!** Which is a bit annoying since I am a completionist, hopefully the other versions of fable are not like that, but is less annoying now that I know I am not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I know from my personal experience of playing on Xbox (I've beaten Fable TLC ~10 times over) that the book quest *will* go away after you've donated all 30 possible books. It's possible that there's a bug in the PC version that causes the quest to not go away. On Xbox, in particular, after you've donated all 30 books and you attempt to talk to the teacher again during class, he tells you something to the effect of "You've done an amazing job helping us restock our library, and we don't need any more books!" And the quest is no longer in the list of active quests.

The chicken kicking quest, on the other hand, does not go away, even after getting all of the possible prizes (i.e. the hat, the key and the emotion), probably since you can still go back to the chicken kicking game anytime afterwards and win money. Again, it's possible that there's a bug on the PC version that won't allow it to give you the emotion prize.

Man, I used to love this game...*so* much nostalgia